# Segmentation fault in determinant function when data types and return types changed from int to float or double

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a "Segmentation fault" error when i run this!
I'm trying to use the hilbert() function array output as input to another function called determinant(). I tried using static, dynamic array and much more. Here's my code: 
(I have to create a hilbert matrix and use that matrix as an input in determinant function to find its determinant)

I am trying to find a 4 by 4 hilbert matrix and then run it by determinant function which contains another deter() function for 3 X 3 matrix.
please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 double arr3[4][4];

 double deter(double m[3][3])
{

 double determinant= m[0][0] * ((m[1][1]*m[2][2]) - (m[2][1]*m[1][2])) -m[0][1] * (m[1][0]
   * m[2][2] - m[2][0] * m[1][2]) + m[0][2] * (m[1][0] * m[2][1] - m[2][0] * m[1][1]);



  return determinant;
}

double determinant(double **a,int o)  //  o denotes order of the matrix
{
    int i,j;              
    double b[3][3];
    int m,n;   
    int c,s=1;    // s is for the signed values; c is used for expanding along the row
    double det;


        det=0;   
        for(c=0;c<=o-1;c++)  // c used for iterating along the row 
        {
            m=0,n=0;
            for(i=0;i<o;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<o;j++)
                {
                    b[i][j]=0; // array b initialized zero      

                    if(i!=0 && j!=c)  // For obtaining the matrix of minor by deleting the first row and the concerned element column
                    {
                        b[m][n]=a[i][j];  
                        if(n<(o-2))   //to allow elements of the minor to be stored, we need to increment m and n as well.
                            n++;
                        else
                            {
                                n=0; // restarting the n values for columns 
                                m++; // increment m for next row values
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            det=det+ s * (a[0][c]*deter(b)); // The main recursive determinant function; a[0][c] denotes the expanding along the row approach; next recursion to find determinant of the lesser order minor
            s=-1*s;  // to get cofactor from minor 
        }


    return(det);
}



double **hilbert()
{

    //int m=4;
  double **array;
    array=malloc(sizeof(int*) * 4);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        {  array[i] = malloc( sizeof(int*) * 4);
        }

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
           array[i][j] = 1.0/((i + 1) + (j + 1) - 1.0);
        }
    }

 /*printf("Hilbert actual is \n");   
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf\t",array[i][j]);
        }
    }
*/
 return array;   
}


 int main()
{
   //double a[4][4];
    int i,j;
    double d;
   // hilbert();
   // double **ab;

      double **aff=hilbert();

/*    printf("\nEnter the matrix elements: ");
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);  //taking the input
        }
    }
    // d=determinant(a,3);         //calling the determinant function
    //printf("\nDeterminant is %d",d);
  */ 
  printf("\nHilbert matrix is : \n");
  for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {   
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf\t",aff[i][j]);  //taking the input
        }
    }

   d=determinant(aff,4);  //determinant function
  printf("\nDeterminant is %lf",d);
  free(aff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At a first glance, the way you allocate the matrix, pass it out of `hilbert()` and into `determinant()` looks just right. What is the problem?

Comment: I just wonder about the `a` - array: You never initialize, but read from it. Replacing `printf("%lf\t",a[i][j]);` by `printf("%lf\t",aff[i][j]);` and just remove your `a` array would make more sense to me IMHO ... Recall: `int *a = {1,2,3}; a[i] == *(a + i * sizeof(int));` and `int b[][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}}; b[i][j] == *(*(b+i) + j);` ...

Comment: @MichaelBeer im getting segmentation fault error. And yes, I corrected the array to aff, its still the same error. I was just trying out different things to make this code work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes an out-of-bounds write at this line:

```
 array[i][j] = 1.0/((i + 1) + (j + 1) - 1.0);
```

The following is the runtime error, and here is a [live test of your code](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/h3dBsnavMdfbDnwM)

=========== Start of #0 stensal runtime message ===========

Runtime error: **[out-of-bounds write]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
-
- Writing 8 bytes to 0x872f050 will corrupt the adjacent data.
- 
- The memory-space-to-be-written (start:0x872f040, size:16 bytes) is allocated at
-     file:/prog.c::66, 23
- 
-  0x872f040               0x872f04f
-  +------------------------------+
-  |the memory-space-to-be-written|......
-  +------------------------------+
-                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
-        the write starts at 0x872f050 that is right after the memory end.
- 
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the write.
- [1]  file:/prog.c::74, 12
- [2]  file:/prog.c::100, 20
- [3]  [libc-start-main]
-
```

============ End of #0 stensal runtime message ============

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a suggested reading:

[Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Then, let's look at `hilbert()`

```
double **hilbert()
{
    // ...
    double **array;
//  ^^^^^^ 
    array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 4);          //  -->  malloc(sizeof *array * 4);
//                       ^^^^^
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc( sizeof(int*) * 4);  //  -->  malloc(sizeof **array * 4)
//                               ^^^^^^    
    }
// ...
}
```

See also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55294828/4944425) by [stensal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926640/stensal), where an out of bounds access is spotted.